# DO i need to execute separate celeryd if i run multiple sites in Django

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Currently i have one site on Django. But i am planning to run more Django sites.

So i want to know that do i need to run `celeryd` for every new site or one is enough.

I am running `celeryd daemon via supervisor

Answer (score 5):

If each site is going to be running on different code, and you plan on using a different celery backend so that the messages don't collide, then you will need to use one celeryd for each new site.

Here is some more info, not a lot but it is something:

http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/browse_thread/thread/85e5aa8458310439